# How to get filepath from sdcard in android

Tags: java, android

When I clicked on button I want to get a `filepath` from a `filename`. I am using custom BaseAdapter for that I am passing `ArrayList<String>`. I am getting file name but also i need absolute filepath from sdcard. Here is my code in getView();

```
String mFileName = myitem.get(position);            
viewHolder.bt_encrypt.setTag(mFileName);
```

In onclick of button  I added below piece of code to get a file when i clicked on button of same row

```
 String fileName = (String) v.getTag();
```

From this how to get filepath ?

**full code**

```
private void getDir(String dirPath){

 item = new ArrayList<String>();
 path = new ArrayList<String>();
 File f = new File(dirPath);
 File[] files = f.listFiles();

 if(!dirPath.equals(MainActivity.root_sd_path)){
   item.add(MainActivity.root_sd_path);
   path.add(MainActivity.root_sd_path);
   item.add("../");
   path.add(f.getParent()); 
 }

 for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
 {
    File file = files[i];
    if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
        path.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            item.add(file.getName() + "/");
        }else{
            item.add(file.getName());
        }
     }  
  }

  SDcardFiles sdcardFilesAdapter = new SDcardFiles(item, dirPath);
  setListAdapter(sdcardFilesAdapter);       

}

public class SDcardFiles extends BaseAdapter{

   private LayoutInflater mInflator;
   String myfilename;
   ArrayList<String> myitem;
   File sdFile;
   private String mFileName;    

  public SDcardFiles(ArrayList<String> fileItem, String fileDirpath){

   myitem = new ArrayList<String>();    
   myitem = fileItem;
   mInflator = MyFiles.this.getLayoutInflater();

   @Override
   public int getCount() {

    return myitem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return myitem.get(position);
     }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
    }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (view == null) {

        view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.myfiles_sdfiles, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.fileName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.file_name);
        viewHolder.bt_encrypt = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.encrypt);                
        view.setTag(viewHolder);                            
    } else {

               viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
           }


    mFileName = myitem.get(position);           
    viewHolder.bt_encrypt.setTag(mFileName);    

    String myFileName = mFileName;  

    System.out.println("mFile====>"+myFileName);

    if(myFileName != null && myFileName.length() > 0){

        viewHolder.fileName.setText(myFileName.toString());

    }            

    viewHolder.bt_encrypt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String fileName =  (String) v.getTag();                 
            System.out.println("inside encryption====>"+fileName);  

                         // Here I need filepath also

        }
```

THANKS

Comment: you have to look for it. My question is why don't you save the whole path to the file

Comment: that will be a long code to write if you get it from fileName. can you post the full code where you add the myitem list?

Comment: Please give an example of the value/content of fileName.

Comment: if you want to find file path from the file name you need to write long code, and may be affect your apps performance. One thing you can do is pass a hash map or sparse array   with file name and file path.

Comment: How did you get the filenames in the first place?

Comment: @Squonk  : Please check my code

Comment: @Prasad : The constructor for your SDcardFiles adapter is... `public SDcardFiles(ArrayList<String> fileItem, String fileDirpath)`. You are passing in the directory path so why aren't you saving that in the adapter? You can prepend that to your file names to get the full path.

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like this

> Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();